# mobile.changePage

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am designing JQuery Mobile application and facing one problem there, i have two pages,page1.aspx and page2.aspx,i have to redirect from page1 to page2,currently i am using window.location.href for redirection,but it is show loading also in address bar. In order to avoid this i want to use $.mobile.changePage.

**Problem:**

After coming to page2 i want to execute the code written in Page2 load event,it's working fine with window.location.href,but while using mobile.changePage it is redirecting but load event is not firing,after coming to page2.aspx if i am refreshing the page it is loading, so my problem is while displaying page2.aspx load event has to fire. can anyone tell me why page2.aspx is not loading while using $.mobile.changePage
if anyone knows the solution,please reply ASAP,its very urgent. Thanks in advance.

Page Structure is as follows:

**Page1.aspx:**

```
    $.mobile.changePage("../Page2.aspx", { transition: "slide", changeHash: true, reverse: false });
```

**Page2.aspx:**

```
$('div').live("pageshow", function () 
{  
     $('#lblTest').text("TestMessage");
}
```

Now when i am writing code like this,page is changing but in load event of page2 whatever code i have written is not executing,

This is the second time i am raising this issue,please help

Answer (score 0):

So do you want JQM to load the second page using AJAX or using normal navigation?

In the first case (AJAX), JQM will load the page but will ignore anything that is outside the  element (including CSS, scripts, etc..).

In the second case, you need to tell JQM NOT to use Ajax but do standard navigation, which will then REPLACE your current page with the new one (just like any normal browser does).

In terms of events, from their [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) you need to know where to place which code....

Please provide a longer code snippet in case this still doesn't work out for you...